Why do so many chazzanim skip "אמרינו האזינה ה' בינה הגיגנו" in שמע קולנו?
Approximately half of the (Ashk'nazi) chazzanim I've heard leading s'lichot either skip or say silently "אמרינו האזינה ה' בינה הגיגנו" in שמע קולנו.
I haven't seen any siddurim say to do this, so I've asked several of those chazzanim why they do it, and the response has always been that they've heard others do that.
I'm therefore curious what the source is for this practice.
I'm aware that the following phrase, יהיו לרצון, is supposed to be said silently.

Artscroll ashkenaz machzorim say to recite it quietly if I remember correctly. Don’t know what their source is

I just checked my Artscroll Machzor (Ashk'nazi), and it only says to say "יהיו לרצון" quietly. I took a picture, though I'm not sure if I can add it here.

Welcome to MiYodeya Yiḥezkel and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!
